# How to make Axios post call to an express parameterized route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-hooks

So I got an express route

```
router.post('/:make&:model&:year', function (req, res) {  
  const newCar = {
    make: req.params.make,
    model: req.params.model,
    year: req.params.year
  }
  Car.create(newCar);
  res.send(newCar);});
```

So this works on above using postman

http://localhost:8000/buildings/Audi&A4&2018

I wanna know how would the Axios post go in react functional component. Here's what I have but it doesn't hit the route in express.

```
const [carFetch, setFetch] = useState('');
const postAxios = async () => {
    const payload = { make: 'Audi', model: 'A4', year: 2018 };
    const { data } = await axios.post('http://localhost:1337/cars/', payload);
    setFetchedData(data);
};
```

But it doesn't work.

~SRJ

Comment: Use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams). E.g. `const params = new URLSearchParams(payload);` and then pass that to axios? --- Also, I don't think you mean to use `.post`? You probably use `.get` instead.

Comment: A proper example would help better. It's a post call to the express.

Comment: What would you like explained? I've made a suggestion, which is not enough for an answer.

Comment: Where and how to use URLSearchParams in the above scenario?

Comment: Actually, if you use `.get`, you can probably just pass the object in as a config property. `axios.get('http://localhost:1337/cars', { params: payload })`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what we're trying to achieve here but here's a solution:
Given your parameters in express are designed the way they are, we need to pass arguments as a string object:

```
const [carFetch, setFetch] = useState('');
const postAxios = async () => {
const payload = `Audit&A4&2018`;
    const url = `http://localhost:1337/cars/${payload}`;
    const { data } = await axios.post(url); 
    setFetchedData(data);
};
```

This should hit the express URL, and should make the post call.

Answer (score -1):

If the request doesn't hit express route handler there should be a problem with url matching.

And if you send the request the way your react code sample shows you should look for data in req.body object at the rout handler.